# Slurm, show all jobs that ended at given date or later

Tags: slurm

So I want to display my job history of all jobs that ended after (including) a date specified by me.

I thought perhaps the information I needed was accessible via the `-E` flag to `sacct`, but I don't really understand exactly what this flag returns. The manual is a bit unclear, I think:

```
 -E end_time, --endtime=end_time

         Select jobs in any state before the specified time.  
         If states are given with the -s option 
         return jobs in this state before this period.
         Valid time formats are...

         HH:MM[:SS] [AM|PM]
         MMDD[YY] or MM/DD[/YY] or MM.DD[.YY]
         MM/DD[/YY]-HH:MM[:SS]
         YYYY-MM-DD[THH:MM[:SS]]
```

It looks to mean "display all jobs that ended before the specified date". But this makes no sense, as the output then should be the entire job history from up until the specified date. If I go back one day at the time , eventually the output is empty - so I have no idea about the logic behind this command.

Can `sacct -u user -E end_time` do what I am after? or is there another flag I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Do not mistaken the `endtime` of the filter with the time period your jobs end. Both `--endtime` and  `--startime` refer to the limits of a time period to which the search must be restricted, not to the fact that jobs were started or ended.

So in your case, the time period you specify has a start date of your choice and an enddate of 'now'. And you only want jobs that are 'completed'.

Try with

```
sacct --state COMPLETED --starttime <date you specify>
```